# Descent direction error using fminunc in matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization

I am optimizing a kernel in matlab, but on one of the loops it outputs the following error:

> Error using lineSearch Search direction is not a descent direction;
> roundoff errors may be affecting convergence.

and exits the whole program. I'm actually fine with there being an error, I just would want it to continue to the next loop rather than exiting the program and making me start all over, only to run into the same error again. Is there a way to just make it just return an NAN or whatever number it managed to hit upon and move on to the next iteration?

Edit:
I have reproduced the error with the following lines of code

```
options = optimset('Display','off','TolFun',4e-16,'LargeScale','off');
par12=[4.45873897125075124848,2.45448132035209054536,398.23544583453281120455];
psfY12=[332.20478974188495158160,105.81515908458436570072,0,217.29169454128577854135,47.84122489713877257600,398.23544583453281120455,186.32064258820469149214,69.24275387165039319370,33.13754887984555352887];
y12=1:9;
fp1D = fminunc(@errfun,par12,options,psfY12,y12);
function [z] = errfun(p,v,x);
%cx = p(1);
%wx = p(2);
%amp = p(3);
zx = p(3)*exp(-0.5*(x-p(1)).^2./(p(2)^2)) - v;
z = sum(zx.^2);
end
```

Also I traced the error to the following line:

```
if strcmpi(output.algorithm, medium)
[x,FVAL,GRAD,HESSIAN,EXITFLAG,OUTPUT] = fminusub(funfcn,x, ...
      options,defaultopt,f,GRAD,sizes,flags,finDiffFlags,varargin{:});
```

But I doing

```
open fminusub
```

returns the error:

> Error using open (line 86)
> File 'fminusub' not found.

Answer (score 1):

fminusub is a private function to fminunc.

One idea is to add 'Display','Iter' to your optimoptions call, so that you can see more details of what the optimizer is doing. It is possible that the optimizer has gotten into a poorly conditioned region, or is close to a local minimum or a saddle point, causing the finite difference approximation of the gradient of your cost function to behave poorly.

One suggestion is to try setting FiniteDifferenceStepSize to some small value in the optimoptions call.

Here's an example:

```
optimoptions(@fminunc, 'MaxIterations', 10000, 'MaxFunctionEvaluations', 50000, 'Display', 'Iter', 'FiniteDifferenceStepSize', 1e-3);
```